# Why does Ctrl+C not work in browsers when copying images?

Tags: windows-8.1, browser, copy-paste

I used to be able to copy images loaded in a browser screen like for example if I load this in the URL

[image]

I would just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on the page and it would copy the image and I could paste it in MSPaint or any image editor.  I could also paste it into a Facebook post or any website that accepts images pasted into them.

But now I can't do that in any browser.

I have Windows 8.1 and the latest Chrome (67 64-bit), Firefox (60 64-bit) and IE 11 browser.

I have also tried this in Windows 7, and it also does not allow it anymore.

Comment: Why do you believe that it isn't copying the image? Have you examined the exact clipboard contents?

Comment: why don't just right click on the image > copy image

Comment: is ctrl+c disabled in browsers now or is it just me?  I can right click and copy image but I am so used to copy pasting using ctrl+c that it bothers me a lot.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams It does not copy because I select the content of the page then copy it and then paste it in both mspaint, notepad and also in a wysiwyg editor (https://html-online.com/editor/) and there is nothing there.  I copy from a text on this page and it paste it nicely in the notepad and wysiwyg.  I select all and copy this page and it paste in the wysiwyg with the images and also on notepad but only the text.

Comment: Neither Paint, Notepad, nor a WYSIWYG editor will show you what the clipboard actually has, only what they can take from it.

Comment: Yes I know that.  But there is no clipboard viewer in Windows 8.1 so i either use a text editor or an image editor to paste its content into.  I'm just asking why copying an image is no longer working when I used to be able do it before.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+A and Ctrl+C does work but only with a few browsers. Make sure you are viewing the image file directly, the url address should clearly represent the image format e.g. (http://.../image.jpg or http://.../image.png).

Make sure the image you are viewing is not being loaded via an iframe or jquery style image viewer as this will not work even on Google Chrome.

**Works with the following browsers**

- Google Chrome

**Does not work with the following browsers**

- Internet Explorer 11
- Microsoft Edge

Comment: whats your version of Google Chrome?

Comment: version 56.0.2924.87

Comment: mine is Version 67.0.3396.79 (Official Build) (64-bit).  I better find a computer with an older version to test.  It may have to do with the updates to chrome.

Comment: https://google_chrome.en.downloadastro.com/old_versions/